# Physical effects in supersymmetric theories of the underlying supermanifold being split or non-split?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, supersymmetry, supermanifolds

Given an $m$-dimensional $C^{\infty}$ manifold $M$ with an $n$-dimensional vector bundle $E$ over $M$, one can use the transition functions of the manifold and the bundle to construct an ($m,n$)-dimensional $(\mathbb{R}^{m,n}_S,DeWitt,H^{\infty})$ supermanifold denoted $S(M,E)$ with body $M$, see Theorem 8.1.1 of [Rogers](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/1878). $\mathbb{H}^{\infty}$ are those functions whose coefficient functions in the Grassmann analytic expansion are real valued, see Definition 4.4.3 of the same book. Supermanifolds that can be constructed in this way a vector bundle in this way are called split supermanifolds.

However, there exist also so-called non-split supermanifolds that can not be constructed by this procedure. Complex analytic supermanifolds are an example of this.

My question now is what are the physical effects in supersymmetric theories of the underlying supermanifold being  spit or non-split?

What (kind of) supersymmetric theories in physics are based on (non-) split supermanifolds and why? How is it decided which type of supermanifold is needed to build a specific theory?

For example which kind of (split or non-split) supermanifolds are applied in the superspace-formalism for supersymmetric quantum mechanics, the MSSM, super Yang-Mills theories, super-gravities, string-theory, etc.?

Disclaimer: Since a week I got no attention on the same question first posted [here](https://physicsoverflow.org/39030/what-supersymmetric-theories-based-split-supermanifolds)

Comment: Wouldn't this issue manifestly not show up in super-gravities because you only care about the smooth structure not analytic so you can use Batchelor/partition of unity?